# Relação entre coleções MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, coleção, relação

Gostaria de saber se é uma boa prática criar uma relação entre duas coleções (*collections*) no MongoDB.

Suponhamos que eu tenha uma coleção para os usuários, com um esquema mais ou menos assim:

```
{ 
  "_id": ObjectId(...),
  "username": "",
  "groups": [
    ObjectId(...),
    ObjectId(...)
  ]
}
```

Mas os ID's colocados no array `groups` estariam se referindo aos ID's dos grupos da coleção "groups".

Isso é uma boa prática ou devo usar SQL para isso?
Se for uma boa prática, como posso criar esse tipo de coisa em MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isso é uma boa prática ou devo usar SQL para isso?

Sim, esta prática (armazenamento de ID referencial em objeto) [é usual em implementações que utilizam MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/).

> Se for uma boa prática, como posso criar esse tipo de coisa em MongoDB?

Utilizando, no objeto que armazena as referências, o [mesmo tipo de dados](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36056603/1845714) utilizado na propriedade `_id` do objeto referenciado.